# How to remove visual "plume" in UnrealEngine 4.9?

Tags: rendering, unreal-engine4

I have some visual effect in my game - something like "plume" (?) from moving objects. For example - video with "plume" after character: https://youtu.be/inMRun0ldzM

How to remove this effect?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bug in UnrealEngine 4.9.0:

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/297802/how-to-remove-visual-plume.html

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/298704/possible-renderer-bug.html